# QGIS DB Manager - ST_Buffer producing null

Tags: gis, postgis, qgis, spatialite

I am working with QGIS' db manager. Running the query

`select Buffer(MakePoint(-122.34567, 45.34232, 4326), 1.01) as buff`

which results in a null result. I cant figure out if I am missing something obvious? Without an error message it has been really difficult to debug. Any ideas? I have a layer that also produces null buffers and I would ultimately like to get that working, but I cant even get a single point buffer to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(-122.34567, 45.34232, 4326), 1.01) as buff
```

It should give you the correct result